# Set MaxMemoryPerShellMB on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, winrm

When I try to set MaxMemoryPerShellMB on PowerShell , i am getting the following error .

**"Set Item : The config setting MaxMemoryPerShellMB cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy needs to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting."**

I am not sure how to set the GPO to "Not Configured . can someone please help

Comment: I'd say `gpedit.msc` or change the domain GPO if there is one (with [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems), with the appropriate permissions). But this belongs to serverfault IMHO.

Comment: Can moderators move questions? I can't, and I have most of the rights a non-moderator can get I think. Not sure if I should vote to close or flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'd say VTC. This could be re-posted on SF in a minute and iirc moderator flags should rather be raised for misconduct (I guess meta.so holds the truth). [how could this be upvoted ? ...]

Comment: [Some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(v=vs.85).aspx)